# Unexpected Python KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, keyerror

I have loaded a CSV file into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

Name     ID    Sex     M_Status    DaysOff
Joe      3      M         S           1
NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN          2
NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN          3

df = pd.read_csv('People.csv')
```

This data will then be loaded into an HTML file.

```
test = """

      HTML code

 """
```

Now for preparing data for the HTML file:

```
df1 = df.filter(['Name','ID','Sex','M_Status','DaysOff'])

file = ""

for i, rows in df1.iterrows():

   name = (df1['Name'][i])
   id = (df1['ID'][i])
   sex = (df1['Sex'][i])
   m_status = (df1['M_Status'][i])
   days_off = (df1['DaysOff'][i])

   with open(f"personInfo{i}.html", "w") as file:
      file.write(test.format(name,id,sex,m_status,days_off))
      file.close()
```

And the error:

```
KeyError: 'days_off'
```

Note: This error is occurs within the for loop.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? This error is generated when you try to grab data from a column which doesn't match the name, or if the column doesn't have that header namne. However, it does.

Error Information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'days_off'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-35e6b916521b> in <module>
      1     name = (df1['Name'][i])
      2     id =  (df1['ID'][i])
      3     sex = (df1['Sex'][i])
      4     m_status = (df1['M_Status'][i])
----> 5     days_off = (df1['DaysOff'][i])    

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'days_off'
```

Comment: Can you post the actual stack-trace from when it crashes? I suspect that the code you're showing isn't representative of the error thrown.

Comment: Please fix indentation. Is ```with``` inside or outside ```for``` loop?

Comment: Do you define inside ```test``` something like ```{days_off}``` ? Or do you put there variables as ```{0}, {1}, ...```?

Comment: `days_off = (df1['DaysOff'])` -> `days_off = (df1['DaysOff'][i])` right?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski. yeah 'with' is inside the for loop and {} is used with the HTML. Information is then placed inside the HTML using the format method

Comment: i think the 'test' should be define like this: test = f'...{name_of_variable}' Could you check this syntaxes: f"""...."""" at start and then {}

Comment: @tangy. Yeah forgot the index

Comment: @MRL the error seems to be unrelated to file writing bits. Can you strip it out to a minimum reproducible example, also mentioning your pandas version(possibly checking for issues filed here https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas).

Comment: @tangy. Addition = 0.24.2. This is actually a minimum reproduction. Interestingly, I never came up with this error when I did some similar work with a dataframe consisting of all strings and integers, and no NaN values. However, I don't think its the NaN values giving me issues here... And I agree, I don't think its anything to do with writing to the file

Comment: If you don't get an answer eventually, I'd recommend posting a github issue too - on the face of it, it seems like an issue within pandas rather than your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this and what a stupid error it was!

Basically there was a space at the end of the header name.

What Python wanted/was expecting:

```
days_off = (df1['DaysOff '][i])
```

whereas I was giving it:

```
days_off = (df1['DaysOff'][i])
```

Very stupid human error. Thanks to all that looked into it though

Comment: but why did this result in a `days_off` key error? and why is python expecting the key with the space?

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch, but your error message suggests that you are trying to access your dataframe column with the key `days_off`, when it should be `DaysOff`. I don't see any place in the code you provided where this happens, but I would double-check your source code file to make sure that you are using the right key name.